# File copy to shared path using java

Tags: java

I want to create directories and copy some files to a shared path.

While trying 
`new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\test_folder").mkdirs();` 
creates directories.

While trying 
`new File("\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\test_folder1").mkdirs();` 
creates directories on Desktop as i kept my class file at Desktop.

Now while running
`new File("\\\\san.ukib.tree\\user\\Desktop\\test_folder1").mkdirs();` , 
does not create any directory.

Here \\san.ukib.tree\ is the shared path where i want to create directories and copy files.
I want to avoid solution of mounting `\\san.ukib.tree` as a drive(say J:/) and copy files to J:/ drive.

Is there is a way to achieve this in Java with SDK libraries only?

Thanks in advance.!!

Comment: san.ukib.tree is windows or linux? Also, do you have appropriate permissions to write at shared location?

Comment: @NikhilJoshi it's a windows shared drive. I have ppropriate permissions on this drive.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to a windows share is impossible using only the JDK. You can use [JCIFS](https://jcifs.samba.org/) to achieve this.